# Reinsert the &undo control on excel

Tags: excel, vba, undo

I wanted to run a macro with the code:

```
  Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Reset
```

But instead, I've run this one by mistake:

```
  Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Delete
```

The problem is that now I can't find the &undo control and I don't know how to reinsert it. For example, I can't run the following line (which worked before), an error message says "Invalid Procedure call or argument":

```
Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Enabled = True
```

I tried to reopen my excel file, and I tried to run the same code in another file, but it seems that the &undo control has disappeared from excel. I even tried to restart my computer, but the same error message is displayed anytime I want to run a code with Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").

Can somebody help me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to my problem. I have to reset the "Standard" commandbar using the following code:

```
Application.CommandBars("Standard").Reset
```